# Condição e Validação de datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Tenho 3 campos: número contrato, data início e data fim.

Como faço para validar dois campos simultaneamente? Ou seja, a data início e data fim tem de estar preenchidas. Se não estiverem, tenho que emitir apenas UMA mensagem (e não duas, como estou acostumado a fazer - uma pra cada campo).

Para submeter este formulário, basta que ou o numero do contrato ou as datas estejam preenchidas. Não há necessidade de preencher os dois.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você resolve dessa forma, com ifs em cascata:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function emitir(){
    var numero = document.forms["formEmitir"].numero.value;
    var dataini = document.forms["formEmitir"].dataini.value;
    var datafim = document.forms["formEmitir"].datafim.value;
    if(!numero && !dataini && !datafim){
        alert("Preencha com o número do contrato ou as datas!");
    } else {
        if(numero && (dataini || datafim)){
            alert("Preencha apenas o número OU as datas!");
        } else if(numero) {
            alert("Será emitido através do número do contrato...");
        } else if(dataini && datafim){
            alert("Será emitido através das datas...");
        } else {
            alert("Preencha ambas as datas de início e fim!");
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="formEmitir">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Seu Contrato</legend>
    <p>Pelo número: <input type="text" name="numero" /></p>
    <p>Pela data: de <input type="text" name="dataini" /> a <input type="text" name="datafim" /></p>
    <p><button onclick="emitir();">Emitir</button></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!